# SQL dosen't create anything in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

This is my code, but when I enter my database under users, nothing was created.
It has worked before.

Here is my database informations

```
$odb = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$odb){ die('Connection Failed!'); }

?>
```

And this is where i would like to create a user.

```
$steamid = $steamprofile['steamid'];

/*Check possible existing data*/

$SQLCheckLoginQuery = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `steamid` = :SteamID");

$SQLCheckLoginQuery -> execute(array(':SteamID' => $steamid));

$countUsers = $SQLCheckLoginQuery -> fetchColumn(0);

if($countUsers <= 0){

$SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid) VALUES :SteamID");
$SQLInsertQuery -> execute(array(':SteamID' => $steamid));
}
?>
```

Comment: Do  you have any error?

Comment: not a single error

Comment: check the condition , if its working

Comment: Have you set the error mode for PDO?  By default, PDO is silent: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php.  Setting it to exceptions will not allow you to ignore an error.

Comment: Database is working, because I have another place where it reads some of the stuff inside the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to have an error in your mysql query, your VALUES should be between brackets:

```
$SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid) VALUES (:SteamID)");
```

EDIT: On your comment you show us the structure of `users`, and the column `avatar` seems to be mandatory. So you should make a default value or add the avatar in your insert query

```
$SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid, avatar) VALUES (:SteamID, :avatar)");
```

Also, you can activate log in order to see if some exception are throwed

```
$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: I don't know what it is, sorry

Comment: Read my answer: `VALUES (:SteamId)`  instead of `VALUES :SteamId`

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried. $SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid) VALUES (:SteamID)");

Comment: Still nothing gets in the database :?

Comment: *Do or do not, there is no maybe* @LFlare

Comment: Along with the answer above, you're not using `bindParam`. You need to add `bindParam(':SteamID' => $steamid)`, you're just sending in an array

Comment: @ThrowBackDewd - That's not necessary.

Comment: @MikkelBertelsen try to debug each step of your script to see if you get the connection, if you enter in your condition. And let us know where your code stuck.

Comment: @MikkelBertelsen for what i understand of your db structure. The avatar column is mandatory and should not be null. You should make a default value, or add it in your insert query

Answer (score 1):

So my fix was:

```
$SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid) VALUES :SteamID");
```

to

```
$SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid) VALUES (:SteamID)");
```

+Adding "NULL" as default in the colum avatar.