# Adding more than one value into my database (PDO)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pdo

I got a problem with my code.
I want to add more than just my `:SteamID` to my database.

Currently this function/PDO runs every time you enter my site.
Working code:

```
/*Check possible existing data*/
$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$SQLCheckLoginQuery = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `steamid` = :SteamID");
$SQLCheckLoginQuery -> execute(array(':SteamID' => $steamid));
// $SQLCheckLoginQuery -> execute(array(':avatar' => $avatarid));
$countUsers = $SQLCheckLoginQuery -> fetchColumn(0);

if($countUsers <= 0){
$SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid) VALUES (:SteamID)");
$SQLInsertQuery -> execute(array(':SteamID' => $steamid));
```

This is what I want to add to my database aswell.

```
**// I want this stuff to be updated every time it runs this section**
$SQLInsertQuery -> execute(array(':avatar' => $avatarid));
$SQLCheckLoginQuery -> execute(array(':steamName' => $steamname));
}
?>
```

The problem is that it wont let me add `:avatar and :steamName` into my database.

Comment: And what is the problem you have?

Comment: It wont add the new stuff to the database.

Comment: The :avatar and :steamName

Comment: why not to add it to the same execute where you  adding :SteamID?

Comment: So add this fields to your query. Do you know how to write queries?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to write it properly.

Comment: the `execute()` function actually performs the query, try using [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), then `execute()` after both parameters have been bound.

Comment: Its quite the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/a/37077765/2377164 i give you an example already on how to add avatar in your query,

Comment: @olibiaz It wont let me do it that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL dosen't create anything in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077583/sql-dosent-create-anything-in-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to bind both of the parameters to the query before calling `execute`.

```
/*Check possible existing data*/
$odb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$SQLCheckLoginQuery = $odb -> prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `steamid` = :SteamID AND avatar = :avatar");
$SQLCheckLoginQuery -> bindParam(':SteamID', $steamid);
$SQLCheckLoginQuery -> bindParam(':avatar', $avatarid);
$SQLCheckLoginQuery -> execute();
$countUsers = $SQLCheckLoginQuery -> fetchColumn(0);

if($countUsers <= 0){
    $SQLInsertQuery = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (steamid, avatar) VALUES (:SteamID, :avatar)");
    $SQLInsertQuery -> bindParam(':SteamID',$steamid);
    $SQLInsertQuery -> bindParam(':avatar',$avatarid);
    $SQLInsertQuery -> execute();
}
```

[More info on bindParam from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: had a typo, `$SQLCheckLoginQuery -> bindParam(':avatar', $avatarid);`

Comment: This works! Thanks sir.